# How do I get the UI object inside of a content presenter?

Tags: wpf, custom-component

I have an `ItemsControl` displaying a list via binding. The list is of a ViewModel type which is then referenced in a `DataTemplate` to display a button. The button has it's UID bound to a GUID from the the view model. When a new view model is added to the bound list, I need to get hold of the button that will be added, as the buttons need to be able to be dragged/dropped by the user. At the moment the closest I can get is finding the ContentPresenter that displays the button, but the content of that ContentPresenter is of type view model.

Is there a way to find the button that has been added? Or should I not used a `DataTemplate` and create the buttons my self in order to access them?

I have used the VisualTree helper to get the content presenter, but have not managed to find the button.

Comment: Please, share your code so far

Comment: As a note, use `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(...)` to get the ContentPresenter.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, I found that this morning. Much better than walking the VisualTree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle the `Loaded` event for the `Button`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Loaded="OnButtonLoaded" ... />
```

---

```
private void OnButtonLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    //...
}
```

You won't be able to get a reference to it using the `VisualTreeHelper` until it has actually been added to the visual tree and loaded anyway.